# PHP - Replace String on Array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make a **String Replace** on a variable that user input. May I know how do I want it to accept (') on the string. Let say for example,

```
$string = ' *this* is 'a' test' ';
$regexes = array('/~(.*?)~/six','/\*(.*?)\*/six'); 
$replaces = array('<i>$1</i>','<b>$1</b>');
$new_string = preg_replace($regexes, $replaces, $string);   

echo $new_string;
```

I can make it to change to **bold** and *italic* text but if the string has ' '' ', it will give an error. How do I want to accomplish this?

Comment: http://parsedown.org/ - Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Use `addslashes($string)`;

Comment: Guys you mean: preg_quote() I presume ))

Comment: @MateiMihai, may I know what parsedown.org is for? Btw, Thanks for the info

Comment: It converts markdown strings to HTML.. It is faster and may be used in multiple situations. Using markdown may be a better solution because it is used very often nowadays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you, use `addslashes` and `stripslashes` as required.

```
<?php
$string = " *this* is 'a' test' ";
$string = addslashes($string);
$regexes = array('/~(.*?)~/six','/\*(.*?)\*/six'); 
$replaces = array('<i>$1</i>','<b>$1</b>');
$new_string = preg_replace($regexes, $replaces, $string);   
echo stripslashes($new_string);
?>
```

This Outputs: **this** is 'a' test'